# Liquid floating in the air, not touching the effector nor the domain

Tags: modeling, animation

I am brand new to Blender so sorry if this is a super easy problem.

I am trying to create a flow of liquid that should fill up a tank.
I created a domain, put effectors under and to the sides and created a uv sphere as liquid flow.

So far everything working fine, I baked all and got a nice flow down that starts to fill the tank, problem is the liquid wont reach the bottom, its up floating in mid air which isn't really what I was looking for.
[image: Flow hanging in the air]
Does anyone know as too why?and how do I fix it?

Comment: I could imagine it has something to do with of your settings - unfortunately you do not show any settings. It could have something to do with margin settings on the effectors, but also the size of your voxels (the orange cube in the bottom left) looks like your resolution might be too low as well. So, margins can be a reason, resolution can be a reason and possibly a lot of other things. Maybe you could upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question.